# Swift nil check performance

Tags: ios, swift, performance, instruments

I have a computed property that does a nil check.

```
var _textSize: CGSize?
var textSize: CGSize {
    get {
        if _textSize == nil {
            // compute _textSize
        }
        return _textSize
    }
}
```

When profiling in Instruments, the `== nil` check appears as:

[image: Instruments]

I believe that the `static == infix<A where ...> (A?, A?) -> Bool` is the nil check. Is this the case and if so are nil checks expensive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer really depends by what you mean with "expensive".

### My point of view

However, IMHO, checking if a value is `nil` is **not** an expensive operation.

It is executed in time `O(1)`, so it's a constant time and does not grow depending on other values.
Finally it's a very easy operation for the CPU.

### Class vs Struct

I suppose there is a difference (in terms of required time) if the computed property does belong to a `Class` or to a `Struct`.

**Class**

In the first case (`Class`) the OS needs to retrieve from the `Heap` the instance of the class and next checking whether the property is `nil`. The `Heap` is on the RAM which is fast (but not the fastest memory on the device).

**Struct**

On the other hand, if we are using a `Struct`, data about the computed property is available on the `Stack` which if faster then the `Heap`.

### Wrap up

So, in conclusion:

1. checking whether the computed property of a `Class` is `nil` is **fast**
2. checking whether the computed property of a `Struct` is `nil` is **very fast**